# Pyinstaller error when add option -w

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller

I write a python network application which have 2 component agent and server. Agent connect to Server to send data. I use pyinstaller to covert agent script to .exe file. If i don't add option **-w** which will help hide Console, the code work fine. But when i add option -w , the code failed to run.
Here is my Agent code :

```
def SocketConnect(Server_IP,PORT):

    # Create Socket
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except socket.error, e:
        log_file.write(time.ctime() + " : Error creating socket : %s\n" %e)
        log_file.close()
        sys.exit(1)

    # Connect
    try:
        s.connect((Server_IP, PORT))
    except socket.error, e:
        log_file.write(time.ctime() + " : Connect : %s\n" %e)
        log_file.close()
        sys.exit(1)

    # Send Data
    data = pickle.dumps({'OS':[OS()], 'CPU':[CPU()], 'DISK' : [DISK()], 'MEMORY': [MEMORY()], 'NETWORK': [NETWORK()], 'FIREWALL' : FIREWALL()})
    try:
        s.send(data)
    except socket.error, e:
        log_file.write(time.ctime() + " : Error sending data: %s\n" % e)
        log_file.close()
        sys.exit(1)

    # Close Socket
    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    config_file = open('AgentConfig.cfg', 'r')  # Open Config File - Read
    log_file = open('Log.txt', 'a') # Open Log File - Write
    Server_IP = config_file.readline().rstrip()
    PORT = int(config_file.readline().rstrip())
    FREQUENCE = config_file.readline()

    # Check valid Server_IP & PORT
    parts = Server_IP.split(".")
    if Server_IP == '' or PORT == '' :
        log_file.write(time.ctime() + " : Server IP or Connect Port is not config !\n")
        log_file.close()
        sys.exit(1)
    elif len(parts) != 4:
        log_file.write(time.ctime() + " : Server IP is not a valid IP !\n")
        log_file.close()
        sys.exit(1)
    else :
        for item in parts:
            if not 0 <= int(item) <= 255:
                log_file.write(time.ctime() + " : Server IP is not a valid IP !\n")
                log_file.close()
                sys.exit(1)
            elif PORT not in range(0,65536) :
                log_file.write(time.ctime() + " : Port must be in range 0-65535 !\n")
                log_file.close()
                sys.exit(1)
            else :
                while True :
                    log_file = open('Log.txt', 'a') # Open Log File - Write
                    log_file.write(time.ctime() + " : Connect to Server at " + Server_IP + " : Port " + str(PORT) + "\n")
                    SocketConnect(Server_IP,PORT)
                    log_file.write(time.ctime() + " : Send data Success !\n")
                    log_file.close()
                    time.sleep(int(FREQUENCE))
```

When i run Agent, it failed to run and the error below show up on Server site :

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.10.111', 21672)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 290, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 318, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 652, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "Server.py", line 116, in handle
    temp_list = pickle.loads(self.data).values()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 886, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
----------------------------------------
```

And here is the related code on Server. It use to receive data from client.

```
def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        try:
            self.data = self.request.recv(4096)
        except socket.error, e:
            log_file.write(time.ctime() + " : Error receive: %s" %e)
            log_file.close()
            sys.exit(1)

        temp_list = pickle.loads(self.data).values()
```

I don't know why this happen. How can option **-w** of pyinstaller can efect to my code ?

Comment: The `EOFError` on the server side implies that closing the console severs the connection before the server expects.

Comment: Make your server handle that particular error more gracefully.

Comment: Hi Mad Physicist, i don't really understand what you saying. When i cover the Server Script to .exe file. It work fine with or without console ( **pyinstaller -w** or just **pyinstaller** ). So i think the problem is just on Agent site right ?

Comment: You get an error on the server saying it's reached the end of it's input. EOF means end of file. It means the server knows the socket has been closed on the other end.

Comment: Yes, as you said "It means the server knows the socket has been closed on the other end" . After send data, i call close() function to close the socket. But how this effect to option -w of pyinstaller ? And about "Make your server handle that particular error more gracefully". Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Handle more gracefully means stick in a try except and don't crash if the error is expected.